# lapply to unionSpatialPolygons in a list

Tags: r, geospatial, polygon, lapply, r-maptools

I have a big list of SpatialPolygonsDataFrame objects I created using `lapply` and `gdal_polygonizeR` (code here: https://johnbaumgartner.wordpress.com/2012/07/26/getting-rasters-into-shape-from-r/) on a list of RasterLayer objects. I now want to union the boundaries of the polygon parts that touch within each SpatialPolygonsDataFrame using `unionSpatialPolygons` (`maptools`). I have tested this by calling an individual SpatialPolygonsDataFrame object, and it seems to work. But, when I try to do it for the list of all SpatialPolygonsDataFrame using `lapply`, I get an error. See code below (very sorry my example is not reproducible) and please provide a solution using `lapply` or alternative. Thanks

```
#convert RasterLayers to SpatialPolygonsDataFrame objects
polyl <- lapply(rastl, gdal_polygonizeR)

#test union of polygon parts within individual SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
tmp = unionSpatialPolygons(polyl[[10]], polyl[[10]]$DN) 

polyl[[10]]  #n = 360 features
tmp          #n = 8 features

#run union on all SpatialPolygonsDataFrame in list
polyl_union <- lapply(polyl, unionSpatialPolygons, SpP = 
polyl, IDs = polyl$DN)  

#Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : not a SpatialPolygons object
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what causes the error. An alternative path you could try is

```
library(raster)
x <- bind(poly)
y <- aggregate(x, "DN")
```

With example data:

```
set.seed(0)
r <- raster(ncol=5, nrow=5, xmn=0, xmx=1, ymn=0, ymx=1)
values(r) = sample(5, ncell(r), replace=TRUE)
rr <- list()
rr[[1]] <- crop(r, extent(0,0.5,0,0.5))
rr[[2]] <- crop(r, extent(0.5,1,0.5,1))
rr[[3]] <- crop(r, extent(0,0.5,0.5,1))
rr[[4]] <- crop(r, extent(0.5,1,0,0.5))
x <- list(r1, r2, r3, r4)  
y <- lapply(x, rasterToPolygons)


b <- bind(y) 
a <- aggregate(b, 'layer')

plot(r)
plot(a, add=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. I am now getting the following different error, though, when I apply your method to my data: 'Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘bind’ for signature ‘"SpatialPolygonsDataFrame", "missing". Maybe gdal_polygonizeR (which I need to use instead of rasterToPolygon for decreasing total runtime) creates a problem?

Comment: I suppose that at least one list element does not have a SpatialPDF object; perhaps because all cells were NA?. That would also explains the error you are getting with your code. Run `lapply(poly1, class)` or `lapply(poly1, is.null)` to find the list elements that you need to remove.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but using your suggested method reveals that all elements are 'SpatialPDF' and 'FALSE', so this isn't the problem. Any other suggestions?